# interface generics

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class and interface is implemented as below :

```
Class1<T> : IClass1<T>
```

now I am creating the property in Class2 :

```
Public IClass<?> MyClassProperty {get; set;}
```

what should be the type I need to give to this generic property , so I can assign it from  the different class3.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **object**? After that you can get the real type with `typeof(value)` (value is available in **set**)

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not atempt to answer it